# sbt eclipse command changed files and packages

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, sbteclipse

I created a new Scala project in eclipse then added a package and Scala object ,
So far so good ...

i want to add external library  so i added a **project** folder with **build.properties**   **plugins.sbt**  files,and another file **build.sbt** in the root project.

in the terminal i compiled  successfully the project with the sbt `compile` task.

the **problem** is that after sbt `eclipse` command the eclipse project changed from Scala project to something else....  all the packages changed to simple folders and the Scala project is ruined

- scala IDE :Build id: 3.0.3-20140327-1716-Typesafe
- scala version :2.10.4
- sbt version:0.13.0

you can see in the image [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you get the `eclipse` command from? I'm guessing you're using [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse).

> I created a new Scala project in eclipse then added a package and Scala object , So far so good ...

If I understand correctly, this is exactly the opposite of what the plugin is intended to do. I think you're suppose to create a plain sbt project, and then let the plugin generate the Eclipse project.